# MarkLogic Partial search & formula values

Tags: search, formula, xquery, marklogic, partial

MarLogic 9.0.8.2

We have xml data as follows in MarkLogic

```
   1.
<group>
    <formula>
        <item>Al</item>
        <role>sur</role>
    </formula>
    <formula>
        <item>As</item>
        <role>sur</role>
    </formula>
    <formula>
        <item>Ga</item>
        <role>sur</role>
    </formula>
</group>

2. 
<group>
    <formula>
        <item>GaAlAs-GaAs</item>
        <role>int</role>
    </formula>
<group>

3.
<group>
    <formula>
        <item>AlGaAs</item>
        <role>ss</role>
    </formula>
<group>
4.
<group>
    <formula>
        <item>GaNAs</item>
        <role>ss</role>
    </formula>
<group>
```

Now if user search for "(Ga AND As)", only 2nd & 3rd xml should be retrieved as it contains in same item

If user search for "Ga AND As", all records

So just wondering how to write xQuery for the same as in 1st case it will kind of contains all search words and in 2nd case, it will contains given word.

What will be best approach for this kind of search requests

Answer (score 2):

You can get the behavior you are looking for if you can influence the end users to write `item:(Ga AND As)` instead. If so, use a container constraint called `item` for element `item`. Something like this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:search(
  "item:(Ga AND As)",
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="item">
      <container>
        <element ns="" name="item"/>
      </container>
    </constraint>
    <debug>true</debug>
  </options>
)
```

To match things like `AlGaAs`, you probably need to expand the query to search for term combinations, and blend in some wildcards. It would match patterns like `*Ga*`, and `*As`. Note that you would have to enable wildcard index options to make that work.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks grtjn for your reply. sorry for late reply. problem with wildcard search is that Ga* will also get value of "GaN" (i have added example)  which is not expected, it should only return "Ga"